# Why does my bashscript not work?

Tags: bash, shell-script, cd-command

So I made a bash script to automatically get `ts3` installed and running on my vps, but for some reason it doesn't work.

The error I get is:

```
> /root/install/ts3install.sh: 4: cd: can't cd to /root/teamspeak3-server_linux-x86/

> /root/install/ts3install.sh: 6: /root/install/ts3install.sh:
> ./ts3server_startscript.sh: not found
```

This is my script:

```
 #!/bin/sh
wget http://dl.4players.de/ts/releases/3.0.11.3/teamspeak3-server_linux-x86-3.0.11.3.tar.gz
tar -xzvf teamspeak3-server_linux-x86-3.0.11.3.tar.gz
cd /root/teamspeak3-server_linux-x86/
cd `pwd`
./ts3server_startscript.sh start
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Are you supposed to execute the installer from `/`? Do the contents of the tar file have a hardcoded full path?

Comment: Uhm I am not familar with linux really I just thaught myself a bit by reading tutorials etc. But when I execute the commands in my bash in Putty everything works fine. Just the bash does not work for some reason :/ Can you maybe tell me in "amateur language" what you were exactly referring to? :P

Comment: type this: `tar -tzvf teamspeak3-server_linux-x86-3.0.11.3.tar.gz` (using `t` to "type" or list the contentx,  not `x` to extract) -- what do you see?

Comment: Why the ``cd `pwd` ``?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not `cd` into `/root/teamspeak3-server_linux-x86`. This is not where the file would have got extracted. It would have been extracted in your current location.

So, the correct script would be:

```
 #!/bin/sh
wget http://dl.4players.de/ts/releases/3.0.11.3/teamspeak3-server_linux-x86-3.0.11.3.tar.gz
tar -xzvf teamspeak3-server_linux-x86-3.0.11.3.tar.gz
cd teamspeak3-server_linux-x86/
./ts3server_startscript.sh start
```

Comment: That script doesnt work for me unfortunately :( And the wget is always downloaded to "/" and not "/root/install" where i want it to be downloaded

Comment: Well the script works now if I exec it from WinSCP via SFTP however when I exec it through my control panel (web) it doesn't work :/

Comment: Can I somehow download the "wget" directly to /root/install ?

Comment: First of all, you are not downloading "wget". You are downloading a "file" using `wget`. And, yes, you can download it to `/root/install`. Just use the `-P` option: `wget -P /root/install http://file-link.tar.gz`